# What is the value of yaw rate from which we can say that the driver has made a wrong move?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics

We can turn or zigzag while driving a car, and its yaw rate value changes consequently. 
From what value of the yaw rate (deg/s) can we consider that the driver has made a dangerous maneuver?

Comment: If the tyres are at risk of losing grip on the road, is the obvious response, though the ability and desire of others to avoid the driver's vehicle need to be considered as well.

Comment: I am only considering the ideal case.

Comment: the word dangerous implies there is a context, not an ideal situation. What is safe on a race track may not be in a busy car prk with pedestrians.

Comment: The answer depends on many things like road conditions, tires, suspension, skill of driver and **how do you define dangerous**.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in the comments to your post, it depends on what you mean by the maneuver being "dangerous". What type of danger? To whom/what? What level of risk?

The above not withstanding, if a potential for injury exists if one loses control of the vehicle, then you would want the yaw rate (angular velocity) to not result skidding. Skidding will occur when the maximum static friction force between the tires and the road is exceeded. Static friction provides the centripetal force needed to keep the vehicle in curved motion. The centripetal force $F_c$ is

$$F_{c}=m\frac{v^2}{r}=mrω^2$$

Where $m$ and $v$ are the mass and velocity of the vehicle, $r$ the radius of curvature, and ω is the angular velocity, or yaw rate.

Skidding will be impending when the centripetal force $F_c$ equals the maximum static friction force = $μ_{s}mg$, where $μ_{s}$ is the coefficient of static friction, or

$$μ_{s}mg=mrω^2$$

$$ω=\sqrt\frac{μ_{s}g}{r}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually tyres skid when the strength of the rubber is exceeded. It is not failure of friction because (a) the rubber doesnt slip across the road; some of it is left behind and (b) friction force does not depend on contact area but tyre grip does.

Comment: I”m not sure I know what you’re talking about. First of all I never used the term “failure”. Second, skidding occurs when the maximum static friction force is exceeded and then kinetic friction force takes over which is generally lower than the static friction force. Finally, any rubber left on the road is due to kinetic friction not static friction because for kinetic friction there is relative motion between the surface of the tire and the road. For static friction there is not

Comment: I am going to ask this as a question, because I think it is interesting and not all that well understood.